# Cannot access the WSO2 Stream Processor Studio service from Docker container

Tags: docker, wso2, siddhi, wso2-streaming-integrator

I implemented a sample Docker image for WSO2 Stream Processor [editor profile](https://docs.wso2.com/display/SP400/Running+the+Product#RunningtheProduct-Startingtheeditor/studio) using the following Dockerfile:

```
FROM ubuntu:16.04
MAINTAINER WSO2 Docker Maintainers "dev@wso2.org"

# set user configurations
ARG USER=wso2carbon
ARG USER_GROUP=wso2
ARG USER_HOME=/home/${USER}
# set dependant files directory
ARG FILES=./files
# set jdk configurations
ARG JDK_ARCHIVE=jdk-8u*-linux-x64.tar.gz
ARG JAVA_HOME=${USER_HOME}/java
# set wso2 product configurations
ARG WSO2_SERVER=wso2sp
ARG WSO2_SERVER_VERSION=4.0.0
ARG WSO2_SERVER_PACK=${WSO2_SERVER}-${WSO2_SERVER_VERSION}*.zip
ARG WSO2_SERVER_HOME=${USER_HOME}/${WSO2_SERVER}-${WSO2_SERVER_VERSION}

# install required packages
RUN apt-get update && \
    DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends --no-install-suggests \
    curl \
    iproute2 \
    telnet \
    unzip && \
    rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

# create a user group and a user
RUN groupadd --system ${USER_GROUP} && \
    useradd --system --create-home --home-dir ${USER_HOME} --no-log-init -g ${USER_GROUP} ${USER}

# copy the jdk and wso2 product distribution zip files to user's home directory
COPY ${FILES}/${JDK_ARCHIVE} ${FILES}/${WSO2_SERVER_PACK} ${USER_HOME}/

# install the jdk, wso2 server, remove distributions and set folder permissions
RUN mkdir -p ${JAVA_HOME} && \
    tar -xf ${USER_HOME}/${JDK_ARCHIVE} -C ${JAVA_HOME} --strip-components=1 && \
    unzip -q ${USER_HOME}/${WSO2_SERVER_PACK} -d ${USER_HOME}/ && \
    rm ${USER_HOME}/${JDK_ARCHIVE} && \
    rm ${USER_HOME}/${WSO2_SERVER_PACK} && \
    chown -R ${USER}:${USER_GROUP} ${USER_HOME} && \
    chmod -R g=u ${USER_HOME}

# set the user and work directory
USER ${USER}
WORKDIR ${USER_HOME}

# set environment variables
ENV JAVA_HOME=${JAVA_HOME} \
    PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH \
    WSO2_SERVER_HOME=${WSO2_SERVER_HOME}

# expose ports
EXPOSE 9390 9715 9615 7714 7614

ENTRYPOINT ${WSO2_SERVER_HOME}/bin/editor.sh
```

When building the above Docker image, you are to provide the Oracle JDK and [WSO2 Stream Processor](https://github.com/wso2/product-sp/releases/tag/v4.0.0-RC3) distributions (`files` directory in the Docker build context must contain these distributions).

I have run the created Docker image with

```
docker run -it -p 9390:9390 wso2sp:4.0.0
```

and without port

```
docker run -it wso2sp:4.0.0
```

forwarding but I am unable to access the editor UI from port 9390. As shown in the logs below, we should be able to access the service through the URL

```
http://localhost:9390/editor (when port forwarding)
```

or else through

```
http://<private_container_IP>:9390/editor (no port forwarding)
```

I also find that the server has started up successfully through the logs, as follows:

```
JAVA_HOME environment variable is set to /home/wso2carbon/java
CARBON_HOME environment variable is set to /home/wso2carbon/wso2sp-4.0.0
RUNTIME_HOME environment variable is set to /home/wso2carbon/wso2sp-4.0.0/wso2/editor
[2017-12-25 22:47:44,035]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.launcher.extensions.OSGiLibBundleDeployerUtils updateOSGiLib} - Successfully updated the OSGi bundle information of Carbon Runtime: editor  
osgi> [2017-12-25 22:47:46,187]  INFO {org.wso2.msf4j.internal.websocket.WebSocketServerSC} - All required capabilities are available of WebSocket service component is available.
[2017-12-25 22:47:46,190]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.metrics.core.config.model.JmxReporterConfig} - Creating JMX reporter for Metrics with domain 'org.wso2.carbon.metrics'
[2017-12-25 22:47:46,211]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.metrics.core.reporter.impl.AbstractReporter} - Started JMX reporter for Metrics
[2017-12-25 22:47:46,269]  INFO {org.wso2.msf4j.analytics.metrics.MetricsComponent} - Metrics Component is activated
[2017-12-25 22:47:46,274]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.databridge.agent.internal.DataAgentDS} - Successfully deployed Agent Server 
[2017-12-25 22:47:46,307]  INFO {org.wso2.msf4j.internal.websocket.EndpointsRegistryImpl} - Endpoint Registered : /console
[2017-12-25 22:47:46,457]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.event.simulator.core.service.CSVFileDeployer} - CSV file deployer initiated.
[2017-12-25 22:47:46,460]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.event.simulator.core.service.SimulationConfigDeployer} - Simulation config deployer initiated.
[2017-12-25 22:47:46,463]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.siddhi.editor.core.internal.WorkspaceDeployer} - Workspace artifact deployer initiated.
[2017-12-25 22:47:46,518]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.cluster.coordinator.rdbms.internal.RDBMSCoordinationServiceComponent} - Cluster coordination has been disabled. Enable it in deployment.yaml to use the clustering service
[2017-12-25 22:47:46,645]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.stream.processor.statistics.api.StatisticsApi} - org.wso2.carbon.stream.processor.statistics.api.StatisticsApi service component has  started.
[2017-12-25 22:47:46,759]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.siddhi.editor.core.internal.StartupComponent} - Editor Started on : http://localhost:9390/editor
[2017-12-25 22:47:46,762]  INFO {org.wso2.msf4j.internal.MicroservicesServerSC} - All microservices are available
[2017-12-25 22:47:46,825]  INFO {org.wso2.transport.http.netty.listener.ServerConnectorBootstrap$HTTPServerConnector} - HTTP(S) Interface starting on host 127.0.0.1 and port 9390
[2017-12-25 22:47:46,828]  INFO {org.wso2.transport.http.netty.listener.ServerConnectorBootstrap$HTTPServerConnector} - HTTP(S) Interface starting on host 0.0.0.0 and port 9743
[2017-12-25 22:47:46,888]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.databridge.receiver.binary.internal.BinaryDataReceiver} - Started Binary SSL Transport on port : 9715
[2017-12-25 22:47:46,889]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.databridge.receiver.binary.internal.BinaryDataReceiver} - Started Binary TCP Transport on port : 9615
[2017-12-25 22:47:46,897]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.databridge.receiver.thrift.ThriftDataReceiver} - Thrift Server started at 0.0.0.0
[2017-12-25 22:47:46,911]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.databridge.receiver.thrift.ThriftDataReceiver} - Thrift SSL port : 7714
[2017-12-25 22:47:46,913]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.databridge.receiver.thrift.ThriftDataReceiver} - Thrift port : 7614
[2017-12-25 22:47:46,917]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.databridge.core.internal.DataBridgeDS} - Successfully deployed Agent Server 
[2017-12-25 22:47:46,930]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.kernel.internal.CarbonStartupHandler} - WSO2 Stream Processor started in 3.181 sec
```

What causes this inability to access the running service? Any suggestions and ideas are highly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

As @Andy Shinn described the listen address for http needs to be set to 0.0.0.0 instead of localhost(127.0.0.1).

You can specify this configuration on SP_HOME/conf/editor/deployment.yaml under listenerConfigurations.

Answer (score 1):

What i'm guessing is happening (based on the startup output) is the container is only listening on `localhost` at that port. The listen address needs to be set to `0.0.0.0` instead of `localhost` (notice that the interface for port `9390` is listening on `127.0.0.1` but `9743` is on `0.0.0.0`).

This is because your connection to Docker containers are through a DOcker bridge on the host that performs NAT. The `locahost` at the container is not the same as `localhost` on your actual host.

There is some information at https://docs.wso2.com/display/APPM120/Changing+the+Default+Ports+with+Offset about ports. You might be able to modify the XML file containing the editor server configuration to listen on `0.0.0.0`.

Alternatively, it looks like HTTPS is listening on `0.0.0.0` for port `9743`. You may be able to use it at https://localhost:9743 (probably with a self-signed SSL certificate).)